# Trigger observeEvent in Shiny even when condition hasn't changed

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, shinywidgets

I am having some trouble getting the functionality in my app that I'm looking for because of the way `observeEvent` works (which is normally very intuitive).

The basic functionality I'm looking for is that a user can input a couple numbers, click "submit", and then a modal pops up to take the user's name. After that, the app records the name and sums the numbers, and then clears the inputs. Then I'd like the user to be able repeat the process using the same name - but the app currently is structured so that the sums use an `observeEvent` that responds only when the name is different (i.e., using the same name twice in a row doesn't work, though I'd like it to). You can see in the app that my attempt at a solution is to reset the input for the `inputSweetAlert` (using `shinyjs`), but it can't access it, I assume because it's not actually on the UI side. I am using shinyWidgets sweetAlerts, which I'd like to continue doing.

Here's an example app:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("shinyjs")

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  numericInput("num1", "Enter a number", value=NULL),
  numericInput("num2", "Enter another number", value=NULL),
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "submit"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    inputSweetAlert(session = session, inputId = "name", title = "What's your name?")
  })

  x <- reactiveValues(val=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$name, {
    x$val <- input$num1 + input$num2
    confirmSweetAlert(session = session, inputId = "confirmed", title = "Success!", text = "Your responses have been recorded. All is in order.", type = "success", btn_labels = c("Ok, let me continue")
    )
  })

  ## A possible approach to a solution...
  observeEvent(input$confirmed, {
    shinyjs::reset("num1") 
    shinyjs::reset("num2") 
    shinyjs::reset("name")
  })

  output$res1 <- renderPrint(paste("Name:", input$name))
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(paste("Sum:", x$val))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Hi, which version of `shinyWidgets` do you use ?

Comment: @Victorp, I'm on 0.4.9.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, weird, when you use `inputSweetAlert` the second time, the value is set to `NULL`. Nonetheless I've implemented @ismirsehregal suggestion in last dev version of shinyWidgegts

Comment: Hmm...oddly enough it now works for me too, though it very clearly didn't have that behaviour before. Either way, thanks for including that behaviour more explicitly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset `input$name` via JS:

```
runjs('Shiny.setInputValue("name", null, {priority: "event"});')
```

Here is a working example:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("shinyjs")

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  numericInput("num1", "Enter a number", value = NULL),
  numericInput("num2", "Enter another number", value = NULL),
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "submit"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    inputSweetAlert(session = session, inputId = "name", title = "What's your name?")
    runjs('Shiny.setInputValue("name", null, {priority: "event"});')
  })
  
  x <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$name, {
    x$val <- input$num1 + input$num2
    confirmSweetAlert(session = session, inputId = "confirmed", title = "Success!", text = "Your responses have been recorded. All is in order.", type = "success", btn_labels = c("Ok, let me continue"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$confirmed, {
    shinyjs::reset("num1") 
    shinyjs::reset("num2") 
    shinyjs::reset("mytext")
  })
  
  output$res1 <- renderPrint(paste("Name:", input$name))
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(paste("Sum:", x$val))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For further information please see this [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html).

**EDIT:** In apps using modules, the call to `runjs()` can be adapted like this in order to namespace the id:

```
runjs(paste0("Shiny.setInputValue(\"", ns("name"), "\", null, {priority: \"event\"});"))
```

Comment: That works (+1) but I don't understand. With this solution, why `input$name` is not `NULL` in `renderPrint(paste("Name:", input$name))`?

Comment: It is `NULL` right after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Yes, so why we get the non-null name in the `renderPrint` and not `NULL` ?

Comment: It is also `NULL` in the `renderPrint` after clicking the submit button (in the background when the modal is open)

Comment: Sorry to bother you mith my misunderstanding. And why does it switch to the non-null name when the modal is closed ?

Comment: because you entered a name?

Comment: Aahh I start to understand. The `inputSweetAlert` is waiting, so when you enter a name, this happens after the `setInputValue`.

Comment: yes, exactly - once you click the submit button, `input$name` is falling back to `NULL`. So everytime you enter a name, even though it's the same as before, it triggers the `observeEvent`.

Comment: What I don't understand now is why the shinyWidgets implementation does not work. See the [code here](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/blob/43b890a9d1137a02bb7160811e02cb513223a005/inst/www/sweetAlert/sweetalert-bindings.js#L58). The input is set to `null` and then it is set to the name. So I expected that this implementation was correct.

Comment: I guess they'd need to use `{priority: "event"}`. Also see [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/928).

Comment: Really nice solution, and thanks for the additional resources. I wish I'd known about that sooner!

Comment: For posterity: When I modularized my app and had to split up the `js` command in order to namespace the `id`, I adapted your solution like this, which continues to work brilliantly: `runjs(paste0("Shiny.setInputValue(\"", ns("name"), "\", null, {priority: \"event\"});"))`

Comment: Thanks for the addition!

Comment: Hello, I can update the package by adding `{priority: "event"}` if it's the solution. It will be less hacky

Comment: For context: added a comment in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/222) raised by @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: @ismirsehregal, I edited your response to preserve the modular piece in case comments are deleted in the future. Hope that's ok with you.

Comment: @phalteman improvements are always welcome! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround. The idea consists in changing the input id at each click on the button.

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("shinyjs")

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  numericInput("num1", "Enter a number", value=NULL),
  numericInput("num2", "Enter another number", value=NULL),
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "submit"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  go <- reactive({
    input$go
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    inputSweetAlert(session = session, inputId = sprintf("name-%d", go()), 
                    title = "What's your name?")
  })

  x <- reactiveValues(val=NULL)

  observeEvent(input[[sprintf("name-%d", go())]], {
    x$val <- input$num1 + input$num2
    confirmSweetAlert(session = session, inputId = "confirmed", title = "Success!", text = "Your responses have been recorded. All is in order.", type = "success", btn_labels = c("Ok, let me continue")
    )
  })

  ## A possible approach to a solution...
  observeEvent(input$confirmed, {
    shinyjs::reset("num1") 
    shinyjs::reset("num2") 
    shinyjs::reset("mytext")
  })

  output$res1 <- renderPrint(paste("Name:", input[[sprintf("name-%d", go())]]))
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(paste("Sum:", x$val))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Also a feasible approach!

Comment: Thanks for this response. A great approach, but in my actual use case, I refer to that input in several other places through the app, so @ismirsehregal's solution is cleaner and will require fewer downstream changes.